# Avoiding many DB GET queries in PHP OOP

Tags: php, database

I'm creating a simple contact form in PHP OOP.
I have 2 classes - Constants with all the global constants and Message that handles stuff related to sending/showing messages.

And here I have a problem. I could make it easily but I want to avoid executing a few queries to get specific data about the message like author, ip or text. And I see 2 solutions - select all the data from DB in the constructor of my Message class or create a new method called e.g. getAllData() and use it only once.

So if I used the constructor solution, it would be impossibility to handle sending and showing messages as well, because it would require different arguments. If I used a different function for fetching all the data, a problem would be solved but I don't feel like it was very OOP.

So maybe I should make 2 classes instead of 1? SendMessage and ShowMessage. But is it ok to use classes this way?

Comment: Why not use JOINs as usually to get data from multiple tables in a single query?

Answer (score -1):

I've always favoured using factories to create objects populated with external rather than polling the data inside the object - it makes for easier code management later in the development cycle - but that's beside the point.

Where is the measurable cost in both approaches? Those I can see are code complexity and performance. Retrieving all the data (to an aggregate object) requires a couple less lines of code than retrieving specific values - not really enough to be a deciding factor. As long as the data is known to be small (i.e. not thousands of data items or more) then there is no significant overhead to having all the data in PHP after it has been retrieved if it is never used - again, no clear argument either way. But the cost of retrieving the data is all about the number of round trips the execution thread makes to to the database - and that makes retrieving all the data in one hot much more efficient (at least with MySQL type databases, it's also much better for DBMS caching).

Comment: So the solutions I considered are ok?